# What's the difference between "important" and "matter"?

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between "You are important to me." and "You matter to me." ?

Comment: Your question might be more appropriate on our sibling site [ell.se]. On EL&U, we expect you to demonstrate some research - for example, include definitions of "important" and "matter" - and explain what it is you find confusing.

Answer (score -1):

To matter (to someone) is a reflexive verb that means “to be important to somebody.” The two phrases are virtually identical, it’s just a choice of whether you want meaning to rest inside the verb or the adjective.

Comment: Here's an example of usage: cowardly down-voting trolls don't matter to me; their behavior demonstrates how unimportant they must be to spend time being negative.